# net.socket.setTimeout does not work with async.eachOfSeries

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am having this issue were if I am not able to connect to a host, Nodejs stalls. The weird part is I had this working with async.eachSeries when it was a array and the port was static. Does anyone know why?

```
client = new net.Socket;
hosts = {'google.com': '443', 'yahoo.com': '80','msn.com': '444'};

client.setTimeout(1000, function () {
    console.log("Timeout has occurred")
});

async.eachOfSeries(hosts, function(port,host,callback) {
    client.connect(port, host, function() {
        console.log('Connected to  ' + host + " on port " + port);
        client.destroy();
        callback();
    });
});

client.on('timeout', function() {
    console.log('client has timed out');
    client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});
```

Thank you,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msn.com connection on port 444 fails and and the last 'callback' (after successful connect) is never called- which is why node stalls.

Check the following code which solves this (notice msn call is now the first one and just times out- I feel it's better for understating the flow).

```
var async = require('async');
var net = require('net');

hosts = { 'msn.com': '444', 'google.com': '443', 'yahoo.com': '80' };

async.eachOfSeries(hosts, function (port, host, callback) {
    client = new net.Socket;

    client.setTimeout(1000, function () {
        console.log("Timeout has occurred")
    });  

    client.connect(port, host, function () {
        console.log('Connected to  ' + host + " on port " + port);
        client.destroy();
        callback();
    }).on('timeout', function () {
        console.log('client has timed out');
        client.destroy();
        callback();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi RLaaa, Thank you so much for the help. I do have some questions, why would a call back happen twice if `clearTimeout(timeout);` wasn't there? Also why do we want to add var timeout; out of the scope of async? If there is a reading resource you can direct me too that works for me as well.

Comment: Good comment- as it wasn't really necessary...I modified the code to reflect that.